# Sharing app screen in android/ios using xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am planing to develop an app where a person will be able to share his/her app screen with someone, its not whole screen sharing of mobile its just sharing screen of the app.

Is there a way in Android and iOS doing this using Xamarin Forms?

Comment: Do you want to share a screenshot?

Comment: @WilsonVargas thansk for you reply, no not screen shot, fully screen broadcasting

Comment: You'd probably be better off doing native UI for this. For iOS in particular, this is going to be a difficult challenge and trying to do this in forms will require a lot of custom rendering.